# Make different `pretty` settings for git-log and git-show

Tags: git, content-management-system, git-log, git-config, git-show

I have this setting in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[format]
    pretty = oneline
```

Which nicely formats my output of `git-log`. However it also changes the output of `git-show` (and `git-status`), which annoys me, because when I use `git-show`, I usually want to see more detailed output than when I'm using `git-log`.

Basically I want the default `pretty` setting of `git-show` to be different than the default `pretty` setting of `git-log`. Is this somehow possibly?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias for `git log` with the particular formatting you want.

```
git config --global alias.mylog 'log --pretty=oneline'
```

To use this alias just switch to the branch you want and type:

```
git mylog
```

You can remove the modification to your `.gitconfig` file and the default behavior will be there when you use `git show`.